# The complement of a knot is aspherical

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, knot-theory

Let $K$ be a knot. Embed $K$ in $S^3$ with (open) tubular neighborhood $N$. I want to show that $\pi_2(S^3\setminus N)=0$ using the Papa Sphere Theorem.

I think that it may be true that there is no embedding of $S^2$ in $S^3\setminus N$ with nontrivial homotopy type and then, by the Sphere Theorem, one could conlude that $S^3\setminus N$ has trivial second homotopy group. I don't see however why should it be true. Maybe my reasoning is not correct...

I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Hint: Use the 3D Schoenflies theorem.

Answer (score 4):

Preliminary fact: $S^3\setminus N$ is *irreducible*, meaning every embedded $S^2$ bounds a ball.  Let $\Sigma\subset S^3\setminus N$ be an embedded $S^2$.  Now think of $S^3\setminus N$ as a submanifold of $S^3$.  By what Hatcher calls Alexander's theorem (or what others call the 3D Schönflies theorem), $\Sigma$ bounds two embedded balls $B_1,B_2\subset S^3$ with $S^3=\operatorname{int}B_1\cup\Sigma\cup\operatorname{int}B_2$ a disjoint union.  Since $N$ does not intersect $\Sigma$, by connectivity $N$ is contained in either $B_1$ or $B_2$; assume $N\subset B_2$.  Then, $\Sigma$ bounds $B_1\subset S^3\setminus N$.

If $\pi_2(S^3\setminus N)$ were nontrivial, the sphere theorem in the orientable case implies there is an embedded $S^2$, but $S^3\setminus N$ is irreducible hence the $S^2$ bounds a ball, and that ball can be used to produce a nullhomotopy.

Comment: 3D Schoenflies only holds if we assume the embedding of $S^2$ is locally flat, or some other regularity condition. Without it, we can just take Alexander horned sphere containing $N$ in the interior and it will not bound a ball. Is it possible to somehow show that we may assume embedding's regularity without loss of generality?

Comment: @Wojowu I was assuming we were in categories where the theorems applied, for instance PL or smooth.  "Embedding" is meant to be with respect to a specific category.

Comment: Since homotopy groups are generally defined using arbitrary continuous maps, I would rather think we are in just the topological category.

Comment: @Wojowu That is true, but the point of the sphere theorem is that it creates an embedding in the category of the smooth/PL manifold.  It's worth knowing that the smooth homotopy groups (everything done in the smooth category) are isomorphic to the usual homotopy groups.  Continuous maps are homotopic to smooth maps, and homotopic smooth maps are smoothly homotopic. (The sphere theorem can provide a smooth sphere despite the fact that topologically embedded spheres are not necessarily homotopic to smoothly embedded/immersed spheres.)

Comment: @KyleMiller Does this imply the title? which is $S^3\setminus K$ is aspherical?

Comment: @love_sodam Yes, $S\setminus K$ and $S\setminus N$ are homotopy equivalent. Also, the argument only depended on $N$ being connected and $S^3\setminus N$ being a manifold (with or without boundary).

Comment: @love_sodam You use the Hurewicz theorem on the universal cover.  The universal cover has $\pi_1=0$ and $\pi_2=0$, and since $\pi_1(S^3\setminus N)$ is infinite, the universal cover is non-compact so $H_3$ of the universal cover is $0$, which gives you $\pi_3=0$, and then since all the higher homology groups vanish, so do the homotopy groups.

Comment: @KyleMiller I see. Thanks (+1).